# Web scraping with selenium to get more information from more events button

Tags: python, selenium

this time I would like to click a button in order to load more real-time searches.
In order to click "more events" button to get more events' link, title, date etc. information. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, you should be able to edit your question and add the sample anchor tag from your comment, properly formatted as a code block, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = "https://www.rsc.org/events/subject/organic"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)

details = []

while True:
    try:
        get_btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ev-more-results-link')
        get_btn.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:

        complete = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divInternalEvents"]/div')

        posts = complete.find_elements_by_class_name('ev-always-col')

        dts = complete.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')

        for idx,post in enumerate(posts):
            title = post.text
            link = post.get_attribute("href")
            date = dts[idx].text
            
            details.append({"title":title,"link":link,"date":date})    
        break
 
print(details)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "https://www.rsc.org/events/subject/organic"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)

while True:
   try:
       get_btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ev-more-results-link')
       get_btn.click()
       time.sleep(2)
   except:
       print("completed")
       break;
```

In case, If you have any problem, feel free to ask.